# Не запускается приложение Java Spring из терминала

Tags: java, spring-boot

Есть приложение. Используется Spring Boot. В IDEA нормально запускается и работает без проблем. Артефакт создается, все библиотеки на месте. В терминале при запуске выдает ошибку:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError : org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication
at com.runtracker.Application.main(Application.java:16)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClas sLoader.java:602)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Cl assLoaders.java:178)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
... 1 more
```

Помогите, не могу найти в чем проблема

```
    package com;
    import org.springframework.boot.*;
    import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.*;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.*;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

    @SpringBootApplication
    public class Main {

       public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
         SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);
         System.out.println("Привет");
   }
```

}

Comment: Класс с методом main добавьте сюда.

Comment: Класс с методом main сюда + все классы которые так или иначе связаны с main так же сюда!

Comment: Не понял куда сюда?

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос класс с методом main.

Comment: А как выглядит командная строка запуска вашего приложения?